# Give double quotes and comma separators in each array

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code :

```
    <?php
$sss = "SELECT tanggal_awal FROM libur_nasional GROUP BY tanggal_awal ASC";
$qqq = mysqli_query($konek,$sss);
$arr = array();
while ( $tam = mysqli_fetch_array($qqq)) {
    $date = $tam['tanggal_awal'];
    $reformat_date =  date("n-j-Y", strtotime($date));
    $arr[] = $reformat_date; 
}
$array_date = implode(",", $arr);

?>



> output : 8-9-2018,8-10-2018,8-17-2018
> output i want to is : "8-9-2018", "8-10-2018", "8-17-2018"
```

could someone help me to get the output i want, thank before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr=['8-9-2018','8-10-2018','8-17-2018'];

$array_date = '"'.implode('", "', $arr) . '"';
echo $array_date;
```

Output ---> *"8-9-2018", "8-10-2018", "8-17-2018"*

Try to implode your array like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your code a bit shorter:

```
$sss = "SELECT tanggal_awal FROM libur_nasional GROUP BY tanggal_awal ASC";
$qqq = mysqli_query($konek,$sss);

while ( $tam = mysqli_fetch_array($qqq)) {
    $arr[] =  date("n-j-Y", strtotime($tam['tanggal_awal']));
}
$array_date = '"' . implode('", ', $arr) . '"';
```

In php you don't need to declare an array before pushing values to it.
Your `$date` variable is not needed as it's just a copy of the `$tam['tanggal_awal']` value.
`$reformat_date` is also not needed as you can place it in the array directly.
The imploding is what is placed between the items, by having `",` there you just need to add a `"` at each end of the string.

Comment: thank for the comment and info, your solution work as well. thank

Comment: No problem. That is what an answer should look like in my opinion. "try this" is just spoon feeding with an solution without giving a why it works.